# Unable to mount Galaxy Note 5 as MTP on 17.10

Tags: usb, mount, mtp

Did a clean install of 17.10 now Gnote 5 shows up in Nautilus but I cant browse the phone. Everytime I try The phone asks if I want to allow access. Tried for 2 days. Nothing seems to help.

Tried this as well
[Problems Mounting Samsung Galaxy Note 5 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882951/problems-mounting-samsung-galaxy-note-5-16-04)

Running Android 7.0 Everything is stock. Haven't rooted the phone.

Everything worked fine on 17.04.

```
dad@dad-System:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2504 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0bda:0301 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. multicard reader
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 016: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Well, I had the same problem using Ubuntu 17.10, until I found http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/android-file-transfer-app-linux . This app gave a rudimentary - and quick - access to photos and mp4-files on my Samsung Galaxy S4 smartphone, even on the sd-card without getting it out of the phone. So it was possible to download and save the data on my notebook. Other ways showed the same results as described above. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

do the following :

```
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs
sudo apt-get install libmtp
sudo apt-get install mtpfs mtp-tools
```

Plug in your phone and do:

```
mtp-detect
```

Note the VID and PID, they will be used later. Then `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` and insert a line that says `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="Insert VID here", ATTR{idProduct}=="Insert PID here", MODE="0666"`

After that restart `udev`:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

If you want to get the contents of an external SD card, remove your phone, Shut down THE PHONE, remove the SD card, Turn on the phone without the SD card, Shut it down, put the SD card in again, turn the phone on, shut down your Ubuntu, then plug the phone in.

Comment: Both of the following lines fail with "Unable to locate package"
sudo apt-get install libmtp
 sudo apt-get install mtpfs mtp-tools

I did try mtp-detect and interestingly enough it shows 
libmtp version: 1.1.13

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.

Comment: do sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. Then try again

Comment: UPDATE : DO THIS COMMAND : sudo apt-get install libmtp9

Comment: also here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/417323/my-mtp-capable-device-is-not-detected-what-can-i-do-about-that

Comment: Tried that link already among other things. I even tried switching from Wayland to Xorg. Running the install libmtp9 just returns libmtp9 is already the newest version (1.1.13-1). I'm stunped. This cable and phone works on all other PCs both Windows and Linux. No other pc is running 17.10 and as I said it worked on this machine until I wiped it and installed 17.10

Comment: the best suggestion I have at this point is to wipe ubuntu ( BACKUP ALL DATA FIRST ) , and reinstall it